# Significance of LOV and LLITE metrics in Lustre

Tags: parallel-processing, lustre

I am looking for metrics that affect/reflect user I/O performance. So far I understand OST and MDT metrics are significant.  But is there any other metrics which get updated during file write/read operation? Mainly I want to know what is the significance of LOV and LLITE metrics in terms of I/O. (As LOV is related to client, I think it  might be significant, but not sure what does it indicate).

Answer (score 0):

The llite module provides the linkage between the Linux VFS and the underlying storage targets.  You could consider this the "POSIX" layer.  The LOV module is what aggregates *data* operations across multiple OSTs into a single virtual object for llite.  If a file is striped over multiple OSTs then LOV handles the split/merge of IO requests and sends them to the appropriate OST objects based on the file layout.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Now, considering I am using multiple threads or say multiple users are trying to create/access files in 1 OST. is it possible to get any idea about this scenario from llite or lov metrics?